# classic asp not connecting to oracle datasource

Tags: oracle, asp-classic

I am migrating an old classic asp application from windows 2003 server to windows 2012 r2. The code is the same. I have set up the system ODBC data source, but I continue to get the "Data source name not found and no default driver specified" error. The connection string I'm using is:

Persist Security Info=True;Extended Properties=DRIVER={Oracle ODBC Driver};Password=*****;User ID=*****;;SERVER=*****;

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm not an ASP developer!

Comment: What's the name of the data source on the old machine, and on the new server? Do they match exactly, i.e. no differences in spelling, capitalization, etc? And why do you have two semi-colons before 'SERVER=' above? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry.. the two semicolons was a typo. The datasource on the old machine and new machine are exactly alike. PROD... all caps.

Comment: Is this a 32-bit app/ODBC drivers?  If so, you need to use the 32-bit ODBC setup.

Comment: Yes. It is a 32 bit application and I am using the 32 bit ODBC setup.

Comment: I have it squared away. Thanks.